# Crontab schedule visualization tool for Windows

Tags: windows, visualization, scheduling, cron

We have a crontab scheduler running on our Unix server. Currently when someone adds a job to the crontab, he has to add the job to an outlook calendar manually.

However, this outlook calendar has lost its functionality, partly due to old jobs not being removed, partly due to number of jobs, partly due to the lack of visualisation options.

I've found this question [is-there-a-tool-that-allows-visualization-of-crontab-entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183796/is-there-a-tool-that-allows-visualization-of-crontab-entries)
but I'm looking for a tool that allows me to load in the crontab schedule file and visualize it a Windows environement.

Does anyone have a good tool for this or an alternative solution ?

Comment: [CircleEye](https://github.com/kylelin/circleEye) might be helpful which based on html and JS for crontab visualization.